# SQL Selecting Data with WHERE ". $variable ."

Tags: php, mysql

my question is: 
I have an issue with my code (SELECTING data from MySql)
This is my code
    `<?php
    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];
    echo $user_email;
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "minehelp");
    $id_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT user_name FROM users_en WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_email . "';"); 
    while ($row_id_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($id_query)){
        print($row_id_query['user_name']);
}
?>`
I want to select data WHERE the "user_name is $user_name"
This is login system, that means the $_SESSION'user_name'
is part of my code and i can't remake it.
Thanks for every answer,
Jakubk-0

Comment: You have not single-quoted the variables `$NickNaming,$PassWording,$Emailing`.  You should be using `prepare()/execute()` however, with placeholders for these.

Comment: See first [when to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks) to understand what went wrong with the SQL, then more importantly, see [how can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and follow some of the examples there for using `prepare()/execute()` with placeholders in the query instead of variables to understand the best way to fix it

Comment: Uses PDO... injects user input into query anyway... *BANG HEAD HERE*

Comment: Read up on the subject => http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements instead of blindly stabbing the meat, *as it were*. ;)

Comment: *"i am working on my own registration system"* - Don't use this unless you know exactly what you're doing and getting yourself into. Here's one that uses PDO with prepared statements and PHP 5.5's `password_hash()` function http://daveismyname.com/login-and-registration-system-with-php-bp - You'll be setup in no time ;) - **Do NOT store passwords in plain text, you WILL be hacked.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried to not use PDO :

```
$insert = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (Nickname, PassWord, Email)
          VALUES ('$NickName','$PassWording','$Emailing')");
```

That will work

Answer (score 1):

Should be looking similar to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (NickName, PassWord, Email) 
    VALUES (:nick, :pass, :mail)";
$conn->prepare($sql);
$conn->execute(array(':nick' => $NickNaming, ':pass' => $PassWording, ':mail' => $Emailing));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**PDO::prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

> Prepares an SQL statement to be executed by the
>   PDOStatement::execute() method.

and **[PDO::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)**

> Execute the prepared statement.

So your *prepare* and *execute* would look like this:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare( 'INSERT INTO users (NickName, PassWord, Email)
                        VALUES (:nick, :pass, :mail)');
$sth->execute( array(':nick' => $NickNaming, 
                     ':pass' => $PassWording, 
                     ':mail' => $Emailing));
```